# WPF and IPAD\IPHONE

Tags: iphone, wpf, ipad

Can WPF Browser application run on IPAD\IPHONE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. To run an XBAP (XAML Browser App), you are required to have .NET 3.5 installed on the client.

See this link: http://www.xbap.org/faq.html

This is obviously not possible on the iPhone/iPad.